# C Why we need `execv()` for redirection?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, system-calls

In my class, the professor showed how we can use `execv()` to do output/input redirection given the fact that `execv()` doesn't replace the process's current file object table (FDT):

But I don't get it, why we need at all to use `execv()` and call `fork()`, how is that different from using parent process to open that file and write to it using `open()` and `write()`.

**Another question:** why parent needs to wait for the child at all?

```
shell code:

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
   close(1);
   open("file.txt",
      O_CREAT …, …);
   char* args[] =
      {"date", NULL};
   execv(args[0],
      args);
} else {
   wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `execvp` instead; otherwise you need to replace `date` by a full path such as `/usr/bin/date`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I know, let's suppose it's in current file

Comment: that's what my professor wrote, is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `execv` you can execute an external command, in this case `date`.

The parent process could write the file by itself with `open` and `write` as you say, but what text are you going to write there?  You would have to write your own code to determine the current date and time, and format it in the correct way.  Executing the `date` command lets you avoid reinventing the wheel.

The `wait` is needed to ensure that the child process has terminated before the parent process continues.  Otherwise, the parent process might finish while the child is still working.  The user probably expects that when your program returns, the file `file.txt` is complete and contains the correct data, and that they can immediately run another command that uses the contents of that file.  Without the `wait`, that could not be guaranteed.

Comment: "Otherwise, the parent process might finish while the child is still working" won't child process terminate when parent is done?

Comment: @lion: No.  A child process created by `fork()` runs independently of the parent, and can continue running after the parent exits.  It's not automatically terminated when the parent exits (though in some cases it can be, having to do with sessions and controlling terminals - it's complicated).   This is how background jobs and daemons work.

Comment: @lion: And even if that were the case, it would make the `wait` even more important - if the parent exited and terminated the child before the child was done, the file might not get properly written at all.

Comment: To add another imortant reason to *always* wait() on child processes somewhere in the parents logic: The wait() call will allow the kernel to cleanup the child process' resources. If not done, the child process will become a *zombie* process. Making sure the child has done its work, before the parent reads the result could be implemented with other mechanisms, but the wait() should still be done.